# How to change the position of a plane within a point cloud?

Tags: matlab

I have x,y,z coordinates in a text file from which I create a point cloud in form of a cylinder. I want to insert a plane in order to extract only certain points (intersection point cloud and plane) to evaluate them later. 
I could already write a code to insert a plane along the z-axis. I used the code posted [here](https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/482984-extract-planes-from-point-cloud) as a basis, which I adapted for my purposes.
My problem now is that the plane does not intersect the point cloud at the place where I am interested in the data. I have already tried to rotate the point cloud around the z-axis what changed the position of the plane, but it also changed the shape of the point cloud so it no longer looks like a cylinder. 
My question now is, is it somehow possible to change the position of the plane without changing the shape of the point cloud?
That's the code I'm using:

```
filename = 'C:\Users\file location\plane.txt';
fileID = fopen(filename, 'r');

%% Read text file as columns and convert cell array into a matrix
ptCloud = cell2mat(textscan(fileID, '%f%f%f','delimiter',',','collectoutput',1));
%Separate matrix into x,y,z
x = ptCloud(:,1);
y = ptCloud(:,2);
z = ptCloud(:,3);

%% Create the plane 
p0 = [0 0 0];
p1 = [0 max(y(:)) 0];
p2 = [0 0 max(z(:))];

 % normal vector of a plane
n = cross(p0-p1,p0-p2);
n = n/norm(n);

    % equation of a plane
    % a(x-x0) + b(y-y0) + c(z-z0) = 0
F = @(X,Y) -n(1)/n(3)*(X-p0(1)) - n(2)/n(3)*(Y-p0(2)) + p0(3);
[x0,y0] = meshgrid([min(z(:)) max(z(:))]);
z0 = F(x0,y0);
    % find distance to plane for each point
    % (using the same formula)
FDIST = @(X,Y,Z) sum(n.*(p0-[X Y Z]));
D = arrayfun(FDIST,x(:),y(:),z(:),'uni',false);
D1 = cell2mat(D);
mindist = 1;                          % minumum distance to plane
ind = abs(D1) < mindist;

mplot = @(p,s) plot3(p(1),p(2),p(3),s);
plot3(x(:),y(:),z(:),'.b')              % all data
hold on
plot3(x(ind),y(ind),z(ind),'or')        % points belong to plane
    % original points
mplot(p1,'^k')
mplot(p2,'^k')
mplot(p0,'^k')
surf(x0,y0,z0,'FaceAlpha',0.5);          % plane

xlabel('X(mm)')
ylabel('Y(mm)')
zlabel('Z(mm)')
title('Plane in point cloud')

hold off

axis equal
```

I have already tried to rotate the point cloud around the z-axis by doing.

```
x = x*cos(theta) - y*sin(theta);
y = x*sin(theta) + y*cos(theta);
z = z;
```

For a better understanding you can see on the following figure how the point cloud with the plane currently looks like.

[image: point cloud with plane]

Comment: when you execute the line `x = x*cos(theta) - y*sin(theta);`, you overwrite your original `x` coordinates. It would be fine if you didn't need them again, alas on the next line `y = x*sin(theta) + y*cos(theta);` you are executing a statement which was expecting the original `x`, not the rotated ones ... Use extra variables (like `x1,y1`) instead of overwriting your original ... at least until you understand what's going on.

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply. Your suggestion was very helpful. I just added the lines to change the rotation right after I separated my matrix into `x,y,z` and named the new variables `x1,y1,z1`. Afterwards I exchanged all `x,y,z` in the code into `x1,y1,z1` and it works pretty fine now.

Comment: If you only wan't to know which point are intersected by the plane you could simply insert your point in the plane equation. For example if your plane is defined by `-2X + 3Y + Z = 4` check which point give the result `4`.